# upnp-up package for openWRT

Tags: openwrt, upnp

I'm looking for a valid, community supported UPnP-UP package, to install and run on my openWRT router machine.

From what I've seen so far, there are many packages of UPnP, but non who support UPnP-up.

Can someone please point me on the right place to look for this package? Or maybe tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is a link regarding UPnP-UP from IEEE -

```
 http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4641337&tag=1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to explain (or link to a definition  of)  UPnP-up: I've worked with UPnP and have never heard of it.

Comment: I've added a link from IEEE to the question

Comment: So it's not a standard, not on track to become one, and not even publicly available... It's entirely possible there are no implementations at all. Even some actual standards in this area have a very poor track record of getting implemented (see DeviceProtection 1.0 spec -- from the short description UPnP-up sounds like it even has similar goals).